# Install latest Konsole on non KDE-based distros

Tags: gnome, konsole

I'd like to install latest `konsole` on Ubuntu 20.10.

I see in the public repo that latest version is `konsole/groovy,now 4:20.08.2-0ubuntu1 amd64`, but I know that the current latest is `21.04.1`.

Is there a way to always have latest version and keep it automatically updated (PPA, flatpak, snap etc...)?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 soon anf that will give you the version you want.

Comment: Have you tried with sudo apt install konsole ?

Comment: @GasparHuerta what do you think? Of course I did and version is `20.08.2`

Comment: @ChanganAuto it's not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

Add the relevant Flatpack repositories, which can be added with two commands:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists kdeapps --from https://distribute.kde.org/kdeapps.flatpakrepo 
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub-beta --from https://flathub.org/beta-repo/flathub-beta.flatpakrepo
```

Then install Konsole from (for the latest versions) the former repository.

Comment: Please modify my answer so that the last sentence is not necessary, and so that zero repositories must be added. For instance, Firefox Nightly can be installed if `flatpak install --from https://firefox-flatpak.mojefedora.cz/org.mozilla.FirefoxNightly.flatpakref` is executed.